# How i can get my aweber API credentials from aweber account?

Tags: forms, api, integration, credentials, aweber

I am working with API and i need following things, i have get first two things but dont know how to get the other two. can you please guide me:

```
$consumerKey = '****'; # replace with your real keys
$consumerSecret = '****'; # replace with your real keys
$accessKey = '****'; # replace with your real keys
$accessSecret = '****'; # replace with your real keys
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AWeber's API documentation explains how to get all your keys, and this blog post in particular, helped me get my keys quickly and easily.

http://engineering.aweber.com/quick-start-api-script-in-php/